# FormData not working with Axios Post request - MERN react Js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I've been trying to make a post request to my server(Node Js+Mongodb which runs on localhost too). Axios.post works properly on the client code, however when i try to use formData it doesn't. I can't seem to find any reason why it's not working.
It leaves no error on the console(which makes it more frustrating).
Here is the client code:

someone pls point me to what I might be doing wrong.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Axios  from 'axios'
export default function InputData() {
    const [inputName, setInputName] = useState("")
    const [inputAge, setInputAge] = useState(0)
    const [inputEmail, setInputEmail] = useState("")
    const [userImage, setUserImage] = useState("")
    const [info,setInfo] = useState("")
    
    var bodyFormData = new FormData();
    bodyFormData.append('name', inputName);
    bodyFormData.append('age', inputAge);
    bodyFormData.append("email", inputEmail)

    const createUser = () => {
        Axios.post("http://localhost:3008/createUser",
             bodyFormData , { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } }).then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
        }).catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
        });

     
  }
  return (
      <div>
          
          <form onSubmit={createUser} encType="multipart/form-data">
              <div>
                  <input type="text" placeholder='enter name' value={inputName} width={400} onChange={(e) => setInputName(e.target.value)} /><br/>
                  <input type="number" placeholder='enter age' width={400} value={inputAge} onChange={(e) => setInputAge(e.target.value)} /><br/>
              <input type="email" placeholder='enter e-mail' width={400} value={inputEmail} onChange={(e) => setInputEmail(e.target.value)} /><br />
                  
                  <button>Submit</button>
              </div>
</form>
          
          </div>
  )
}
```

axios: "^0.27.2",
react: "^18.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points:

1. You're probably not seeing any errors (output) in the console because you're submitting the form. You can change your `onSubmit` handler to include [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```js
const createUser = (e) => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3000/createUser", bodyFormData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
       .then(console.log)
       .catch(console.error);
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

2. You can also keep it as is and see the previous output by persisting the logs of your browse across requests, in Firefox this checkbox: [image]
3. You should add `method=post` to your form

Answer (score -1):

I think you will receive all the data from the event [createUser method] on submitting the form, Try removing the header If you still have problem try as below, If you still have the problem check the server side Post method Params

```
let data = { name: inputName, age: inputAge, email: inputEmail }
Axios.post("http://localhost:3008/createUser",data )
.then(function (response) { console.log(response);  })
.catch(function (response) { console.log(response);  });
```

Comment: This works...  that is not my problem at at all. the issue is  with the use of FormData

Comment: see this Axios [Reference](https://github.com/axios/axios#formdata) and check this axios.postForm to your check list